# Запятые в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, сложносочинённые-предложения

> Хочешь ли ты, и есть ли у тебя время со мной общаться?

Как правильно расставить запятые, и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the comma here.

Rosenthal et al, *Справочник…*, § 30.2:

> Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
>
> 1. Общим может быть второстепенный член предложения: *Вскоре после восхода набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь* (П.); *У Ивана Ивановича большие выразительные глаза табачного цвета и рот несколько похож на букву ижицу* (Г.); *Глаза у всех устремились и носы вытянулись по направлению к письму* (Гонч.)

In your case, the common dependent constituent is *со мной общаться*.